# Ionic 4 nested firebase list based on month

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

I am trying to list events based on months names list.

**My firebase data looks like this:**

[image]

**The output that I am trying to reach is like this:**

[image]

As you can see, I have the date of each event entered manually. I need to list each event under the month that they belong to.

**Update:**
My coding approach using angularfire2 is as following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
selector: 'app-tab2',
templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page {

eventsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
events: Observable<any[]>;


constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {

this.eventsRef = db.list('/events');
this.events = this.eventsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes => 
    changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
  )
);


}


}
```

I am stuck trying to pull out the events grouped by months, so my issue is not UI my issue could be typescript thing.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to group the data coming from firebase by date. Then you display it in html similar to the code below (although I'm using ion-item as example for UI):

Supposed like you have the data grouped by like this one:

```js
groupedEvents = [{"EventDate": "2019-10","Events": [{"title": "Test","subtitle": "testsubtitle", "date": "2019-010-18"}]}]

<ion-item-group *ngFor="let group of groupedEvents">
  <ion-item-divider>{{group.EventDate|date:'MMM y'}}</ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of group.Events">
    <p>{{item.date|date:'dd MMM y'}}
    <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{item.subtitle}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
```

Comment: Thank you @dom.macs, My issue is not UI, I think my issue is how to pull out the events from firebase grouped by months using angularfire2. I have added my approach so far. Help will be appreciated.